# Adding library to project,Android

Tags: android

I am following tutorial called Motion Gesture Recognition using Tensorflow and Android.

https://lembergsolutions.com/blog/motion-gesture-detection-using-tensorflow-android

I would like to use the library they developed previously in mine own app. I was wondering if it should have been added automatically as I added maven dependency and implementation in my *build.gradle*
How exactly does it work? Will the folder download itself or do I have do put in on my own in my app folder?

What i did was:

```
repositories { maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/rii/maven/" } }
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'uk.co.lemberg:motiondetectionlib:1.0.0'
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you edit your `build.gradle` file, click `Sync Now` button above, it will download dependencies and make them available in your project.

Comment: I did sync it,and it succeed but there is no folder with the library,and that's my question. Should it download itself?

Comment: It must download the library itself.

Comment: So it did not,why?

Comment: They shared a link, you can check it here: https://github.com/ryanchyshyn/motion_gestures_detection/tree/master/MotionGesturesDemo

Comment: Yes,I know,my all my build gradle files looks exactly the same,and i have NDK downloaded as well,still nothing happens

Comment: Did you run your code after implementing the library?